# Why can't a method that takes a vector take the return vector of its own output?

Tags: c++, vector

I'm confused between the subtle differences of passing vectors

This is some part of my program

```
void print(vector<vector<char>>&field)
vector<vector<char>> bomb(vector<vector<char>>&field)
```

I encountered a case where I can't do something like this

```
print((bomb(bomb(field)));
```

The error is

```
error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'std::vector<std::vector<char> >&' from an rvalue of type 'std::vector<std::vector<char> >'
             print(bomb(bomb(field)));
```

But if I add a const to the method definition to

```
void print(const vector<vector<char>>&field)
vector<vector<char>> bomb(const vector<vector<char>>&field)
```

Then this will work

What is the difference between

```
1. vector<vector<char>> bomb(vector<vector<char>>&field)
3. vector<vector<char>> bomb(const vector<vector<char>>&field)
4. vector<vector<char>> bomb(const vector<vector<char>>field)
```

I believe 1 is passing a vector by reference, which is what I've been doing before. How come I can't do something like bomb(bomb(field)) without the compiler complaining?

Comment: `const` means what again? Reconsider!

Comment: `Bomb(..)` is returning a temporary `vector`.  Temporaries can not be bound to non-const reference parameters.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1565600/873025

Answer (score 2):

The return value of `bomb` is an object, not a reference. The return value is a temporary object. Hence, you cannot use it when the expected type is a non-const reference.

Analogy with simpler objects:

```
int foo(int& i) { return i+2; }
void bar(int& i) {}

// Can't use
int i = 10;
bar(foo(i));
```

That is a problem since `foo` returns a temporary object. Its return value cannot be used as an argument to `bar` since `bar` expects a non-const reference.

If the return value of `bomb` can be changed to a reference,

```
vector<vector<char>>& bomb(const vector<vector<char>>&field);
```

without breaking how it works, then you can use:

```
print((bomb(bomb(field)));
```